# JSONSerializer.toJSON the result is empty

Tags: java, json

I am trying to serialize a Java Object to a string, in JSON format. I thought that the JSONSerializer was the right answer, but when I call it, the result has a size equal to 0.
For the moment my object to parse is really basic:

```
public class Location {
    public double _latitude;
    public double _longitude;

    public void setLatitude(double latitude){
        this._latitude = latitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(double longitude){
        this._longitude=longitude;
    }
 }
```

And my call is pretty simplistic too:

```
JSONObject jsonResponseObject = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(location)
```

Reading the [documentation](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONSerializer.html#toJSON%28java.lang.Object%29), I thought that it would just magically work with any object...

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The documentation says, "Accepts JSON formatted strings, Maps, arrays, Collections, DynaBeans and JavaBeans." Your location is none of these

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I was referring to the parameter of the function, which is said to be of type "object", and my Location inherits from this Object, so it should correspond to the "any java Object" description. Or at least I thought so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class doesn't provide any getters. Add the following methods:

```
 /**
 * @return the _latitude
 */
public double getLatitude() {
    return _latitude;
}

/**
 * @return the _longitude
 */
public double getLongitude() {
    return _longitude;
}
```

The following test:

```
Location l = new Location();
l.setLatitude(1.0d);
l.setLongitude(2.0d);

JSONObject jsonResponseObject = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(l);
```

returns a well-formed json string:

```
{"latitude":1,"longitude":2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used jsonlib before, but I think it would work as you expected if you convert it to a JavaBean. In short, implement Serializable, write getters and setters properly and it should work.

**EDIT :** This [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions) would be helpful, I guess.

Comment: Many thanks, at the end appareantly Serializable is not mandatory, but you were totaly right with the getters.